# «По биатлону» или «в биатлоне»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги, управление

*Я занял первое место **по** биатлону.*

А в чем тут ошибка? Нужно, что ли, ***в** биатлоне*?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно будет сказать: «Я занял первое место *в соревнованиях*  по биатлону».
Устоявшиеся словосочетания:

- соревнования *по* биатлону, Кубок мира *по* биатлону, сборная команда *по* биатлону, чемпион города *по* биатлону;
- события,  достижения, успехи *в* биатлоне, конкуренция, фаворит, аутсайдер *в* биатлоне.

Речевые особенности спортивного репортажа (на примере трансляций Чемпионата мира по биатлону): https://nauchkor.ru/uploads/documents/587d36435f1be77c40d58af9.pdf
В статье рассматриваются особенности стиля англоязычных электронных изданий, освещающих спортивные события в биатлоне: https://e-koncept.ru/2016/86577.htm
Сленг биатлонистов: https://otvet.mail.ru/question/90027888

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от того, что хочет сказать автор.
Я занял первое место по биатлону (Дательный падеж и предлог "по"):

- были разные соревнования, но по биатлону вышло занять первое место;
- по истории биатлона;
- по просмотру биатлона...